# Looping on php not running on javascript

Tags: javascript, loops

I want to add a date input field, which is automatically filled one month later than the current month. but I have trouble when looping on javascript. please help me

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
        var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
        var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

        <?php for($xd=1;$xd<=10;$xd++) { ?>

        var x = 3; //initlal text box count
        $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
            e.preventDefault();
            if(x <= max_fields){ //max input box allowed
                $(wrapper).append('<div><div class="col-xs-4"><label>Cicilan Uang Muka/Tunai Ke-' + x + '</label></div><div class="col-xs-4"><label>Nilai (Rupiah)</label><input type="text" name="nilai_rp_ke_2_sd_n[]" class="form-control"/></div><div class="col-xs-3"><label>Tanggal Jatuh Tempo</label><input type="text" name="jth_tempo_cicilan_ke_2_sd_n[]" class="form-control pull-right" value="<?php $d=strtotime("+$xd Months", $cicilan_ke2); echo date("d/m/y", $d); $xd++; ?>" readonly="readonly"/></div><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
                x++; //text box increment
            }
        });

        <?php } ?>

        $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
            e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: i see no need to mix php in here at all, it should all be done with js

Comment: Is your code in a .PHP file?

Comment: Can you help me in print next month in the date column....well, this is in the form .php file

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's not working on javascript, because php and javascript working in different side. Php server side and javascript client side.

Except you can pass this to your view using php as a returned variable from some of your PHP method

```
public function yourFuncName(){
    ...

    $returnVal = '<script type="text/javascript">
                     $(document).ready(function() {
                         ...
                         var xdMin = '. @$xdMin .';
                         var xdMax = '. @$xdMax .';
                         var xd = 0;

                         for(xd=xdMin; xd<xdMax; xd++){
                             ...
                             ...
                         }
                     }
                  </script>';
    ...
    return @$returnVal;
}
```

Hope this works for you.